# The Login PC IP Address should be stored in MySQL database

Tags: jhipster

I need some clarification regarding log for obtain system IP address for user in MySQL table

When i login my jhipster gateway application (either admin or user) , its has been display for our UI part. During this i can get IP address for user who login my application.Also this can be stored in my MySQL database. Is any possible ways are available in jhipster? Please refer me

Note:One option available for getting user IP address but this is only for database change log lock table. In this table if the schema is locked the it was displayed for IP as well as host name

Example:
This is table for databasechangeloglock. I exactly want this user system IP for each and every login(either admin or user)

```
    Id      LOCKED          LOCK GRANTED            LOCKED BY
   '1',     '1',        '2017-05-11 17:49:42'    'WDSI-LT19 (192.168.0.119)'
```

Comment: Not a JHipster specific question , this is pure Spring MVC / servlet API. Please do some research and you'll find tons of examples not only on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah thank you, But jhipster provide same IP get function when liquibase is locked that is database was locked that so i am asking do same as get IP who login my application

Comment: Liquibase is locked by your application, not by a user (meaning that IP is your application's IP).  Follow Gaël's advice for how to get a user's IP when they make a request.